# How to pass method variable through terminal using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, terminal

Having a very simple method saved in `test.rb`:

```
def say_good_night(name)
    result = "Good night, #{name}"
    puts result
end
```

How can I pass a variable to this method through terminal?
My initial thought was `test.rb say_good_night("Johny)`

Comment: If you just want to interact / play with your code, there's [IRB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html) – interactive ruby. You can load a file into it via `irb -r ./test.rb` and then enter `say_good_night("Johny")` at the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

`ARGV` is an array of string variables passed to your script. So

```
def say_good_night(name)
  result = "Good night, #{name}"
  puts result
end

say_good_night(ARGV[0])
```

or even

```
ARGV.each { |name| say_good_night(name) }
```

and call it as

```
ruby test.rb KOFI_113
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: you're welcome :)